# How to display two images in each row of Custom listView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I want two display two Images and and two Text Views in each row of the List View. I have tried this but images are not displayed.

This is code of Customized list view source, `custom_listview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_ListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBook1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/book1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleBook1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgBook1"
        android:text="Book1 Title Here" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBook2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBook1"
        android:src="@drawable/book2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleBook2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtTitleBook1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtTitleBook2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTitleBook1"
        android:text="Book2 Title Here" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Java code, `Main.java`:

```
    package my.islamic.books.lib.app;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends ListActivity {

    String[] booksTitles = { "Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.id.text1, booksTitles));

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        int[] booksCoverPhotos = { R.id.imgBook1, R.id.imgBook2, R.id.imgBook1,
                R.id.imgBook2};

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
            // super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            super(context, resource, objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_body, parent, false);

            ImageView imgView_book1 = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgBook1);
            ImageView imgView_book2 = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgBook2);
            TextView txtView_bookTitle1 = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTitleBook1);
            TextView txtView_bookTitle2 = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtTitleBook2);

            txtView_bookTitle1.setText(booksTitles[position]);
            imgView_book1.setImageResource(booksCoverPhotos[position]);
            imgView_book2.setImageResource(booksCoverPhotos[position]);
            txtView_bookTitle2.setText(booksTitles[position]);

            return row;
        }

    }// end class

}
```

And also when I'm making comment any imgView_book1 or imgView_book2 in the above Java code, then it's displaying one image in each row of listView, but why not both images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImageView method `setImageResource(int resId)` gets an id of your drawable as a parameter.
For example, `R.drawable.your_image`.
Read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) document.

Comment: Also you must avoid the View inflating operation every time the getView is called. It is a waste of memory. ListView has been created with a view recycle mechanism wich allows to resuse the same view evrytime

Comment: Yeah I got it now. I was committing a mistake. You  absolutely right. Thank u so much. it helped me.

Comment: U r welcome. I think you can close this question, or accept some answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use BaseAdapter to Achive Your requirements
see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387474/adapter-in-android-in-list-view/12387706#12387706)
And [Here](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-custom-listview-example.html)

Comment: You should help him with his current code or extract essential part from your link.